# maven rpm package fails with "ERROR!!!!SGSBASE value is not set.Hence exitting"

Tags: rpm-maven-plugin

I am tring to generate a simple rpm, but rpm goal fails with the following error

```
[INFO] --- rpm-maven-plugin:2.1x:rpm (default) @ private ---
[INFO] Creating spec file C:\apps\eclipse\workspaces\algo-ws-new\private\target\rpm\SPECS\private.spec
SHARDA. in buildPackage....
ERROR!!!!SGSBASE value is not set.Hence exitting
```

here is the plugin config

```
<build>
    <plugins>
                <!-- create RPM -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1x</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <copyright>2012</copyright>
                        <distribution>myproj</distribution>
                        <group>System</group>
                        <packager>Internal</packager>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                        <release>1.0.1</release>
                        <prefix>/opt/myproj</prefix>
                        <mappings>
                        </mappings>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>rpm</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Java version: 1.6.0_27, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.

Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_27\jre

Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252

OS name: "windows xp", version: "5.1", arch: "x86", family: "windows"

Answer (score 0):

seems the issue is that the rpm-maven-plugin is a company specific interanl 'enhanced' version

will work with the original version